# Swift 3.0 NSFetchRequest error

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

Just watched `Whats new in Swift` in WWDC videos, they have made a number of changes to SDK and the APIs in it. So when heard about the `NSManagedObject` `fetchRequest` thing, I directly jumped in and started implementing it.

So as per the WWDC, the old NSManagedObject fetching model changed completely. This is a snippet I wrote in Swift 2.2, long back.

`let answers : Answers = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(EntityNames.Answers.rawValue, inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Answers`

Now I tried to do the same in Swift 3.0, here we go.

`let answers : NSFetchRequest<Answers> = Answers.fetchRequest // WWDC video style`

Then I got this error

`Cannot convert value of type '() -> NSFetchRequest< NSFetchRequestResult >' to specified type 'NSFetchRequest<Answers>'`

Then I changed the code to this

`let answers : NSFetchRequest<Answers> = Answers.fetchRequest()`

Then I got this error

`Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<Answers>' to specified type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'`

So I have changed the code a bit and the error gone away. But now I don't have an instance of `Answers` `NSManagedObject`, I have an instance of something else, by using this instance I can't access the properties of my `Answers` `NSManagedObject`. I want to do `fetchRequest` in Answers.

What do you think about this? Let me know your comments please.

---

So I have solved it by using this way

`extension Answers {
    @nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Answers> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Answers>(entityName: "Level");
    }
}`

And fetched like this

`let answers : NSFetchRequest<Answers> = Answers.fetchRequest()`

Then I thought of making it more precise, like this

`let answers = Answers.fetchRequest()`

And shown the error `Ambiguous use of fetchRequest()` Why??

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample code in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html has errors ...

Comment: @MartinR Updated question.

Comment: That ambiguity was already observed in the "duplicate". It arises because `Animal` interits a `fetchRequest()` method from `NSManagedObject` with a different return type. You can file a bug report and see if Apple improves it.